# Magento2 : admin controller not working

Tags: magento2, admin-controller

i created a button in the order/view page in magento2 backend, and would like to call a controller when button in clicked.

In my module, I added :
etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="adminhtml">
        <route frontName="xstateupdate" id="xstateupdate">
            <module name="My_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Conroller/Xstateupdate/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Controller\Xstateupdate;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    public function execute()
    {
Breakpoint on something;

    }
}
```

In order to check if my controller was working, I manually entered the url :
www.xxx.com/admin_toto/admin/xstateupdate/xstateupdate/index.php But it reloads magento backend page and does not trigger my breakpoint...

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

When attempting to access modules/functionality in the backend (Adminhtml), Magento checks for the presence of the secret `Form Keys`, and if/when someone does attempt to access an action and doesn't supply a valid FormKey and/or supplies an Invalid FormKey - the Adminhtml AbstractAction (Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction) will route the user Admin UIX defined Startup page (which is usually the Dashboard page)
[ This mechanism serves a "security checkpoint" to prevent users from accessing portions of the Backend that they don't have access to ]

To prevent the check for FormKey you have essentially have two options available to you:

*(a) Disable Secret Key Validation checks*

> *Navigation:* Stores -> Settings : Configuration -> Advanced : Admin -> Security -> Setup "Add Secret Key to URLs" to "No"
>
> It's important to remember that doing so will turn off Secret Key
>   Validation, and therefore *may* make your application vulnerable.

*(b) Turn off Secret Key Validation for your controller*

> Specify the action(s) you wish to exempt, from the FormKey check, in
>   the "$_publicActions" attribute of your Admin Controller.  The syntax
>   to define the attribute is as follows:
>
> protected $_publicActions = ['ENTER_NAME_OF_ACTION'];

Example:

```
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_publicActions = ['index'];

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "My Hello World! Controller";
    }

}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create controller directory under Adminhtml directory.
Like: My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Xstateupdate\Index.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the path as you told me, changed the namespace of Index.php accordingly, recompiled but same result...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this. I had the same problem.
After too much time of debugging I found the solution.

You cannot enter the url in the backend directly.
Either add a menu link to the controller or add a button with uiComponents.

Reason was, the key in the url will be different when you access it via button or link.